# History tracking for Formula fields

Tags: formula-field, history-tracking, field-history

Formula fields can't be enabled for history tracking. There's a workaround where a new date/time field has to be created for every formula field with formula as now() which would be updated via a field update for a workflow on the formula field (onchange of the formula field). Are there any other workarounds for this? Also, instead if the fields on which the formula fields are dependent are marked would it serve the purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following options:

- Enable History tracking on fields which are used in the formula calculation. Based on these fields, you can easily estimate what the value of the formula field would be before and after the value changes.
- Create a new field similar to formula field but not auto calculated. Write an after trigger on object and copy the data from the formula field to the new field. And enable history tracking on it.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I personally think it's better to enable history tracking on fields which are present on formula field rather than writing a new trigger for this.